# Strange code highlighting and reformatting code completion doesn't work

Tags: phpstorm

I got Phpstorm 7.1 (Lubuntu) version and i have weird issues. 
When I'm writing html code in smarty(*tpl) file editor doesn't close my div's and all the time i got error (screenshot  and i don't have proper code highlighting.

After i reformat code phpstorm reformating code like javascript I think , not html.

Can somebody tell me how to repair it ?
i tried to reinstall , restart etc. 
Screenshots below
[red spot in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPF14.jpg)

[after code reformat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QbG5.jpg)

[zoom for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJH50.jpg)

EDIT: ADDED SCREENSHOT FROM SETTINGS

[screenshot from settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTn4Z.png)

Comment: Please post a screenshot of `Settings | Language Injections` -- sounds like you have accidentally injected different language into `<div>` tag or some another place (maybe even into `src` attribute).

Comment: @LazyOne I added in post.

Comment: Everything looks fine there in `Settings | Language Injections`. I've checked your first screenshot again -- you seems to have an error in your code .. you have extra closing `</script>` tag (you already have it closed few lines before). Maybe that's why? You can also try placing that file into brand new empty project -- does it behave the same? If still nothing -- please upload & share that file so that I can have a look locally.

Comment: Deleting <script> will help